# Arrayformula Int

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, nested-if

How would I adjust this formula to not expand to infinity, but only expand if the adjacent row contains a value?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Invoice Date"; INT(B2:B)})
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Invoice Date"; IF(A2:A="";;INT(B2:B))})
```